# How to Copy URLs from a word document to another document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that is stuffed with codes and URLs that are lying all over the document.

I've been trying to find out how I can extract **all the URLs** in this word document and have them pasted on another document?

the URLs all have the same website which starts with https://subdomain.domain.com ..

the problem is .. i will need the full URL link which usually ends with a .jpg

i have tried googling but all i find are solutions on how URLs of hyperlinks can be extracted. Couldnt find a solution on my situation so i hope you guys can help!

Comment: please mark the answer

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code to send the results to C:\temp\my_links.txt. You can edit the code to change the destination.

```
Public Sub GetUrls()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim outfile As String

    outfile = "C:\temp\my_links.txt"
    Open outfile For Output As #1
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
    r.Select

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "https://subdomain.domain.com/*.jpg"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
         Write #1, Selection.Text
    Loop

    Close #1
End Sub
```

When I run this on a test file, I get this in the the output file:

```
"https://subdomain.domain.com/res1/joe.jpg"
"https://subdomain.domain.com/res2/cat.jpg"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: trying to run the code but i think i have more data than 199. so the immediate window stops displaying the rest. could you help mend the code where the results get printed in a new word document instead? I guess this way the 199 limit wont happen!

Comment: I edited the code to send results to a file. That should address having more than 199 links.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse the document and find all the URL's for you and output the array to a new `Document`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindLinks()
  Dim p As Paragraph
  Dim vSplit As Variant
  Dim nIndex As Integer
  Dim sURLs() As String
  ReDim sURLs(0)

  ' find each URL and add it to an array
  For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    vSplit = Split(p.Range, " ")
    For nIndex = 0 To UBound(vSplit)
      If InStr(vSplit(nIndex), "https://stackoverflow.com") > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve sURLs(UBound(sURLs) + 1)
        sURLs(UBound(sURLs)) = Replace(vSplit(nIndex), "src=", "")
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' create a new document and output the array
  Dim sURL As Variant
  Documents.Add
  For Each sURL In sURLs
    Selection.TypeText sURL
    Selection.TypeParagraph
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: hi Brax thanks for helping out.. the script ran well but this every line of output was something like this, " src="https://subdomain.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1608-7a9fa682e3651b02.jpg?size=96184&amp;height=640&amp;width=640&amp;hash=710eee30989aa7a871e3e682d4923e28" "

anyway we i can just have the output that shows the URL from https: to the last part of the URL - either jpg or jpeg?

Comment: I added a `Replace`.